# Liquibase throws error when yaml file containing SQL has semi-colons

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase to update some tables and I seem to run into an error that whenever my `.yaml` file has a `;` in it, it throws the error (only put in part of it as it just repeats the same error message):

> SEVERE 1/11/18 11:39 AM: liquibase: _master.xml: Tables/Team/Team.updateTeamNames.yaml::1::mayj4: Ch
>   ange Set Tables/Team/Team.updateTeamNames.yaml::1::mayj4 failed.  Error: You have an error in your S
>   QL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to us
>   e near 'UPDATE Team SET Name ='B' WHERE Name ='Y'; UPDATE Team SET Name ='C' WHERE Name ' at line 1
>   [Failed SQL: UPDATE Team SET Name = 'A' WHERE Name = 'X'; UPDATE Team SET Name ='B' WHERE Name ='Y';
>    UPDATE Team SET Name ='C' WHERE Name ='Z']
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c
>   orresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Team SET Name ='B'
>   WHERE Name ='Y'; UPDATE Team SET Name ='C' WHERE Name ' at line 1 [Failed SQL: UPDATE Team SET Name
>   = 'A' WHERE Name = 'X'; UPDATE Team SET Name ='B' WHERE Name ='Y'; UPDATE Team SET Name ='C' WHERE N
>   ame ='Z']

This is the command I am using as well:

> liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath=C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.13 --logLevel=severe --changeLogFile=_master.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resource?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" --username=root --password=badpassword123 update

Here is the `.yaml` file which has the full SQL.

```
---
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    author: mayj4
    id: 1
    changes:
        - sql:
            sql: 
                UPDATE Team SET Name = 'A' WHERE Name = 'X';
                UPDATE Team SET Name ='B' WHERE Name ='Y';
                UPDATE Team SET Name ='C' WHERE Name ='Z';
```

**What I'm using**

- Liquibase **3.6.2**
- MySQL Connector Java **8.0.13**
- MySQL Workbench & Server **8.0.13**

I've tried adding `splitStatements: true` to the `.yaml` but this makes no difference as suggested by [the Liquibase documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html).

**Update 1**
It seems when even removing the semi-colons it still fails, so would be to do with running multiple queries.

Comment: Either you obguscate your logs without anonimizing yaml  or I just dont see related queries ;(

Comment: Oh man I am so silly, thank you for pointing that out! Updated it so it is more clear

Answer (score 1):

You can try using '**>**' to merge multiple sql statements into single executable statement.

```
- changeSet:
  author: Bob
  id: 1
  changes:
    - sql:
        comment: DML statements to rectify previously added names
        dbms: mysql
        sql: >
            UPDATE Team SET Name = 'A' WHERE Name = 'X';
            UPDATE Team SET Name ='B' WHERE Name ='Y';
            UPDATE Team SET Name ='C' WHERE Name ='Z';
```

Comment: Now thats looks even better.

Comment: @Saumil is > part of Yaml?

Comment: YAML supports '>' (folded style) to combine multiple statements in to single statement, here it could be used to combine into single, and can be executed as SQL statements one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
         - UPDATE Team SET Name = 'Maria' WHERE Name = 'Samurai';
         - UPDATE Team SET Name ='Ray' WHERE Name ='Knights';
         - UPDATE Team SET Name ='Stephen' WHERE Name ='Vikings';
```

or

```
   - sql:
        sql: 
             sql1
   - sql: 
        sql:
             sql2
```

and so on.

dash `-` indicates that entry is part of sequence, adn since you want to execute sequence of SQLs this should help. (you can try some variansts, but `-` syntax is the way to go.)
Personaly, your syntax look strange (as why should I nest sql inside sql) but I am not an expers since I havent use liquidbase with yml configuration.